# Get all HTML list element using Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Currently I am working on a project which requires me to parse some data from an alternative website, and I'm having some issues (*note I am very new to **PHP** coding*.)

Here's the code I am using below + the content it returns.

```
$dl = $html2->find('ol.tracklist',0);
print $dl = $dl->outertext;
```

The above code returns the data for what we're trying to get, it's below but extremely messy provided you would like to see [click here](https://pastebin.com/wB5UjaDZ).

However, when I put this in a foreach, it only returns one of the `a href` attributes at a time.

```
foreach($html2->find('ol.tracklist') as $li) 
{
    $title = $li->find('a',0);
    print $title;
}
```

What can I do so that it returns all of the `a href` elements from the example code above?

**NOTE:** I am using simple_html_dom.php for this.

Comment: What if you don't pass the 0? That means "return the first item found" according to the documentation. Without the second parameter an array should be returned instead. Then you'd need to foreach through those results as well, however. Alternatively, `$html2->find('ol.tracklist a');` might return an array of all the anchor tags within an ordered list with a class of "tracklist".

Comment: @stratedge here's the content I get if I `var_dump($title)` after changing it to the method you recommended, http://i.imgur.com/V29lp6r.png

Comment: What does your desired output look like? Or maybe what part of the Anchor do you need?

Comment: @stratedge I'm trying to get the download link where it says `dopefile.pk`, thanks for all the help btw!

Comment: The answer below from @Ghost is essentially what I was going to comment, looks like it should get you what you need

Comment: In case it's still not clear, you were iterating `ol`s which there's only one of instead of `li`s  which there are a bunch of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the markup, just point directly to it, just get it list then point to its anchor:

```
foreach ($html2->find('ol.tracklist li') as $li) {
    $anchor = $li->find('ul li a', 0);
    echo $anchor->href; // and other attributes
}
```

Comment: @Herbo just traverse it just like you'd normally do, its already presented in your markup, for each `<li>` tag, get the `ul -> li -> a`, the `0` represents the first element which is the one you want. glad this helped